# How to capture the status code of an IActionResult Method return in a variable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, http-status-codes

I have the following method:

```
public IActionResult DoSomeThing()
    {
        try
        {
            Some code...
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I have another method from which I must capture what the DomeSomething () method returns to me in a variable:

```
public void OtherMethod()
    {
        var result = DoSomeThing();

        if (result == Here I need to compare with the result, for example if it is a 200 result or Ok, do the action)
        {
            Do an action... 
        }
    }
```

I need to extract the status code, for example result == 200 for it to execute an action.

Comment: Is `OtherMethod` in the same application as `DoSomeThing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually use `HttpClient` to perform such operations. You can see my example below.

In your `Startup`, add

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

In your controller:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
   
public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
public IActionResult DoSomeThing()
    {

        return Ok();
    }
public void OtherMethod()
    {
        var URL = "https://localhost:xxxx/home/DoSomeThing";
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URL);
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = client.Send(message);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
        //...
        }
        else
        {
        }

   }
```

Test result:
[image]

You can see more about `HttpClient` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0).